# Ubuntu 22.04.3 dual boot on successful but needs quality checks : Other sofware and driver missing

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04

I have a Lenovo Slim 7i (Windows 11 home). I have dual-booted in Ubuntu 22.04.3 using a bootable USB (created from Rufus software).

More precisely, I :

- Partitioned my disk to free 100Go for Ubuntu (I realize that it is not too much, so I wonder if I can easily free more space for Ubuntu without reinstalling it?)
- Disabled secure boot on windows
- Boot in Ubuntu using the USB drive that had the Ubuntu OS
- I successfully installed Ubuntu and was able to use it from now

However, I noticed some differences in my system setup from various tutorials online.

1. Nothing is listed in Software and Updates> Other software. This seems weird considering all the other tutorials add some repositories listed in this section.

[image: Software and Updates/Additional Drivers: nothing listed]

2. In Sofware and Updates> additional Drivers, nothing appears, and yet again, I notice that some additional drivers are listed in some tutorials.

[image: Software and Updates/Other Software: nothing listed]

I am a new Linux user looking to develop durable and efficient practices in this environment, so I would like some quality checks regarding the installation and to know that I have proper settings for normal/basic usage.

Answer (score 1):

> Partitioned my disk to free 100Go for Ubuntu (I realize that it is not too much, so I wonder if I can easily free more space for Ubuntu without reinstalling it?)

Yes, you can; resizing is rather simple if you know what you are doing. 1st time might be daunting. Mind that 25Gb is enough and you can use a 2nd disk or partition as personal storage. That includes the NTFS (windows) filesystem.

> Nothing is listed in Software and Updates> Other software. This seems weird considering all the other tutorials add some repositories listed in this section.

It will show repositories when you install 3rd party software. I have one line for Opera browser.

> In Sofware and Updates> additional Drivers, nothing appears, and yet again, I notice that some additional drivers are listed in some tutorials.

That depends on your hardware. I have an LG Gram that has an Intel GPU and an Intel NIC so no additional drivers for me. For nvidia cards there will be a list. Command line: `ubuntu-drivers` command can show you all available drivers (incl. 3rd party).

> so I would like some quality checks regarding the installation and to know that I have proper settings for normal/basic usage.

There is not really such a thing. I would start using Ubuntu and see what you like and not like. Just keep your system up to date.

We do have lots of commands to show details of your system: `lscpu` for your cpu, `lsblk` for blockdevices (ie disks), `dmidecode -t memory` for memory modules, `dmidecode -t bios` for bios info (to install `sudo apt install dmidecode`)

Some tips:

Everything you change (adding/removing software, changing the theme, adding a background, changing settings; basically anything) you can do from command line so don't just do that from the desktop: find the command line method, save it into a text file and next installation you can use that text file to execute those commands. A re-install is going to be a breeze to do.

Keep your USB. You can use it to re-install but also as a repair tool, and for resizing your partitions. There is also a dedicated [gparted live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) for disk management.

Regarding software:

I would advice to install "Tweaks". It has some extra options you can set from the desktop that you otherwise change through command line.

See if the current video player is good enough for you. If you need a full feature install VLC or SM Player.

Opera and Brave browser have a built-in free VPN so if you need that install one of those 2.